# How to clean spots/stains from marble?

Tags: staining, marble

No idea where this came from. Just noticed today. Can't tell what it is. I tried to scrub it semi-hard (don't wanna do too hard for fear of scratching) with a towel and water and did not succeed in cleaning. Is it oil/grease? Feels weird on my finger. Appreciate your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: To check if it is oil or grease, use a mild mixture of dish detergent and water.  The marble looks well sealed, so soap should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. What do I do eith the mix and how does it tell me if its oil or not?

Comment: Dab some on a paper towel, wipe across the spots, scrub vigorously, rinse, dry, and look.  If the spots are gone, it was either dirt or grease.

Comment: Thanks. If I scrub too vigorously won't the marble scratch?

Comment: Not with a paper towel.  There is no need for much abrasion in this scenario.  If it is oil, it will be soaked up layer by layer with each wipe.

Comment: You say it "feels weird on your fingers", this is a good sign as it means the stuff is on top of the marble and should be able to scrub it off.  If it gets absorbed into it you would not feel anything on the surface but still see a stain.  Try the soapy water scrub as already suggested and let us know how it worked.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bleach is safe to use on marble.  Take a dish scouring pad and a heavy bleach mixture - wear gloves.  Scrub away.

Comment: I would not use a scouring pad as this will scratch the marble, made that mistake once scrubbing my wife's crystal vase trying to get the scum line off, I did not realize how bad it was scratched until it dried, my wife was not happy. Marble will be easily scratched with a scouring pad.

Comment: There are basically two types of "scouring pads"  on the market.  Those designed for bare metal, and they will scratch.  And those designed for non-stick teflon/plastic surfaces.  This later type will not scratch most things.  Always be careful as the "dirt" may be abrasive too.